# Creating a virtual environment using HTML5/Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm going to be working on a project soon where I'll need to create an explorable environment similar to a game map using HTML5/Canvas and I was wondering where I might find some resources to get started. The closest thing I've found to what I want to do is here: http://www.isogenicengine.com/ (direct link to video: http://vimeo.com/71436906) - The CasinoRPG game is generally what sort of look/feel I'm going for, except I don't need that much interaction, just the ability to move around and look at the buildings. I'm curious to find out what else is out there that can accomplish something like this. I've also looked at http://raphaeljs.com/ and http://snapsvg.io/ but these seem very barebones for what I'm trying to do and will require a lot of environment type development like movement and perspective and such. Isogenic is my current primary option, but I was wanting to find out what else is available.

I'm very novice to HTML5/Canvas development but have a lot experience with Javascript, so I'm just trying to find the best place to start working on this type of project. Thanks!

Comment: Stackoverflow deals mainly with coding related questions. So you might ask your question on Stackoverflow's new sister site that deals with software recommendations: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks, I went ahead and posted over there as well. Is it a problem to post in both places?

Comment: Ok, so I tried my question over there and they put my question "on hold", saying what I'm asking is "unclear"....

Comment: I hate to "bounce you back" to softwarerecs, but your question isn't a coding question and will likely be closed here too.  I suggest you try to clarify your question and post it again there.  Be brief. Be specific. I'm more of a "business guy" than a "game guy" so I don't have recommendations myself.  Good luck and come on back when you have coding questions! :-)